# IServiceProvider does not return a Singleton instance

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I'm experiencing with `.Net Core` and I'm currently facing it's DI engine.

My Project is a class library, therefore, asp's binding is irrelevant here.

I followed the tips from [this article](http://andrewlock.net/using-dependency-injection-in-a-net-core-console-application/) in order to make DI work.

## now, to the juicy part:

I have made a service provider that looks like this:

```
public static class ServiceProvider
    {
        public static IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            //Singletons
            services.AddSingleton<IInstance, Instance>();

            //Transients
            services.AddTransient<IDate, Date>();
            services.AddTransient<IMath, Math>();
            services.AddTransient<INumber, Number>();
            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

I have then tried executing it in a static class that looks like this:

```
public static class MySingleton
    {
        public static IInstance Instance
            => ServiceProvider.GetServiceProvider().GetService<IInstance>();
    }
```

and in order to test the singleton behavior, I have tested it like this:

```
[Test]
        public void Instance_HundredTimes_ReturnsSameInstance()
        {
            //Arrange
            const int callCount = 100;
            var results = new IInstance[callCount];

            //Act
            for (var i = 0; i < callCount; i++)
            {
                results[i] = MySingleton.Instance;
            }

            //Assert
            Assert.That(results.Distinct().Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
        }
```

the test results came back negative and instead of having a single reference after the distinct (cause it is a singleton) I'm still left with a hundred instances.

am I doing anything wrong?

did I miss anything in configuration?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of `IServiceProvider` each time you access `MySingleton.Instance` (by calling `ServiceProvider.GetServiceProvider()`).

Comment: I was assuming `BuildServiceProvider()` keeps my configuration as a singleton... if that's the case, I have to Lazy load or simply maintain a static instance of the provider, one way or the other?

Comment: Based on source code, I don't see any `static` modificators on classes involved in DI that would make the `ServiceProvider` a shared one. Yes, it's up to you to keep a single instance of `ServiceProvider` in your application if your are not already provided with one.

Comment: alright, so can't totally avoid the `static/lazy` code... thanks though, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem:

My problem laid in not keeping my `IserviceProvider` instance in MySingleton

## Solution:

**TL;DR**

have a static instance of `IserviceProvider`

**Code Refactor**

refactor `ServiceProvider` to Look as following:

```
public class LodashServiceProvider
{
    private static readonly Lazy<IServiceProvider> LazyServiceProvider;

    static LodashServiceProvider()
    {
        LazyServiceProvider = new Lazy<IServiceProvider>(InitializeServiceProvider);
    }

    public static IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider() => LazyServiceProvider.Value;

    private static IServiceProvider InitializeServiceProvider()
    {
        var services = new ServiceCollection();

        //Singletons
        services.AddSingleton<ILodashInstance, LodashInstance>();

        //Transients
        services.AddTransient<ILodashDate, LodashDate>();
        services.AddTransient<ILodashMath, LodashMath>();
        services.AddTransient<ILodashNumber, LodashNumber>();
        return services.BuildServiceProvider();
    }
}
```

I'd like to thank [Kiziu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6804888/kiziu) & [Sefe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6859983/sefe) for their solutions to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is in this code block:

```
public static class MySingleton
{
    public static IInstance Instance
        => ServiceProvider.GetServiceProvider().GetService<IInstance>();
}
```

What you are doing here is to call `ServiceProvider.GetServiceProvider().GetService<IInstance>()` **each time you access the property**. That means do not actually *have* a singleton. What you want to do is to set the singleton instance once:

```
public static class MySingleton
{
    public static IInstance Instance
    {
        get;
    } = ServiceProvider.GetServiceProvider().GetService<IInstance>();
}
```

Additionally, you have a similar problem when you create your services. You create a new `ServiceCollection` each time you call `GetServiceProvider()`. You probably don't want that. You probably want something like this:

```
public static class ServiceProvider
{
    private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider = null;

    public static IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider()
    {
        if (serviceProvider == null) 
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();

            //Singletons
            services.AddSingleton<IInstance, Instance>();

            //Transients
            services.AddTransient<IDate, Date>();
            services.AddTransient<IMath, Math>();
            services.AddTransient<INumber, Number>();

            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
        return serviceProvider;
    }
}
```

Comment: the whole point of `AddSingleton<TInterface,TImplementation>()` is that it adds a singleton that I should not manage myself..

Comment: and as kiziu already mentioned, `return services.BuildServiceProvider();` was my issue here

Comment: @shirbr510: Then you should probably not create a new service collection in `GetServiceProvider`. That's also in my post.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, but why does keeping the `ServiceCollection` matter if anyways I need to keep an instance of `IServiceProvider`?

Comment: P.S: does calling `services.BuildServiceProvider()` on the same `ServiceCollection` instance will generate the same `IServiceProvider`?

Comment: @shirbr510: Why would you build the service proveder again on each call. Check my update to the answer.

Comment: I have accidentally read  "you should probably create a new service collection" instead of "you should probably not create a new service collection", my bad